# HTML JS error logging input

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<p>Enter some text</p>
<form>
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<button onclick="log();">Go!</button>
</form>

<script>
function log() {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    console.log(input);
}
</script>
```

When I click the button, it refreshes the page, clearing the log. I originally tried using `<input type="submit">` but when I click any type of button, it refreshes. How would I stop this?

Comment: use `type="button"` on your button so it doesn't submit the form

Comment: an alternative trick is to set the onsubmit variable of the form as follow: `<form>onsubmit="return false" > .... </form>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with:

```
    <p>Enter some text</p>
<form action="" method="">
    <input name="userInput" type="text" id="userInput" />
    <button type="button" onclick="log()">Go!</button>
</form>

<script>
    function log() {
        var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        console.log(input);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

only add `return false` to you js.
Learn about [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say with your example, but generally if you are trying to prevent an action that would do something like a page refresh from carrying out that default behavior, you would use the [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method on the event handler.  So your function would become

```
function log(e) { // passing in the event to the handler as "e"
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    console.log(input);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

edit:
Updated with Patrick's notes in mind, although I still don't see an attempt to page refresh in the snippet, even with no `type` attribute, or type of `button` or `submit`.

```html
<p>Enter some text</p>
<form action="" method="">
    <input name="userInput" type="text" id="userInput" />
    <button onclick="log(event)">Go!</button>
</form>

<script>
    function log(e) {
        var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        console.log(input);
        e.preventDefault()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @HughChalmers -- see my edit-- I don't see your code trying a refresh in the snippet-- is there anything else going on in your page?

Comment: @anied, OP does not have the `type="button"` attribute on their button which is why your form doesnt try to submit in your snippet. Also `log()` will not automatically get the `event` object passed when using `onclick` attribute it would need to be changed to `onclick="log(event)"`

Comment: Also SO snippet iframes do not allow form submissions so you wouldnt see a submission anyway, you would see a _"Blocked form submission..."_ error message in the console

Comment: Yes, I figured that might be true-- tried doing a window.location.href and it reset it thought, which is why I thought it might.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Enter some text</p>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="userInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="log();">Go!</button>
</form>

<script>
    function log() {
        var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        console.log(input);
    }
</script>
```

So just add **type="button"**